# How convert json object to array in symfony 3 with doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am usign Symfony 3 with Doctrine for get data from db, after get the data, it send to client for add to datatable.

For use the data in the datatable I need a array as follow:

```
[
 {"id":1
 "app": "stack"},
 {"id":2
 "app": "reddit"}
]
```

But when I do the query as follow:

```
  $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

        return $qb = $qb->select('a')
        ->from('AppsBundle:App', 'a')
        ->orderBy('a.'.$columnOrder, $order)
        ->setFirstResult($start)
        ->setMaxResults($length)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

I get as "json object arrat" as follow:

```
{
     "0": {"id":1
     "app": "stack"},
     "1": {"id":2
     "app": "reddit"}
    ]
```

Any idea for get the data as the other representation.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with PHP's array_values() function:

```
$json_out = json_encode(array_values($your_array_here));
```

Code: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/ofuW7)

Comment: This work, but now when send data to client, the quotes of the "id" and "app" was changed to \u0022 and datable not recognice the id and app field, any idea?

Comment: With array_map I get this error "reset() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given"